# Scrapy: how to scrape a link inside a table with conditionals

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, scrapy

i'm a total newbie in python and scrapy  and i have to scrape a website built entirely with tables (almost 80 tables).

The structure of the website is something like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="header" colspan="2">something</td>
</tr>

</table>
<br/>
<table> 
<tr>
<td class="header" colspan="2">something2</td>
</tr>

</table>
<br/>
<table>
<tr> 
<td class="header" colspan="2">something3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

But inside one of  one of those tables there is a list of members and I need to extract the profile information of each member, but each profile is variable, so the table with its information changes, depending on the privacy settings.

The table i need to scrape is something like this, but with many members:

```
<table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4" class="header">members</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="title">Name</td>
                <td class="title">position</td>
                <td class="title">hours</td>
                <td class="title">observ</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="c1">       
                    1.- <a href="http://profiletype1" target="_blank">Homer Simpson</a>
                </td>
                <td class="c1">
                    safety inspector
                </td>
                <td class="c1">
                    10
                </td>
                <td class="c1">
                    Neglect his duties
                </td>
            </tr>
<table>
```

Then I looked at the code, and I noticed that there are 2 types of profiles, and queries with xpath do not cross each other.

Then the question is how can I extract the profile information of each member, taking into account that when I open the link I can find two different types of profile. I guess I need a code that does something like this

```
def parse(self, response):
if this xpath query doesn't work
try this one
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you kinda already answered your question, and the solution is very domain specific for me to be able to give a proper answer. Anyway I will try to give you an idea of how I would approach the problem.

```
def parse(self, respose):
    test = response.xpath("//some expression that only works in method one").extract_first()
    if test is not None:
      return self.parse_with_method_one(response)
    return self.parse_with_method_two(response)

def parse_with_method_one(self, response):
    # your logic

def parse_with_method_two(self, response):
    # your logic
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but now i'm facing another problem.